# Cannot “remember picture” with TikZ in ConTeXt

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

In an attempt to connect two inline nodes as I used to in LaTeX, I wrote the following code:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
\starttikzpicture[remember picture]
     \node (A) {Node 1};
\stoptikzpicture
Hi world
\starttikzpicture[remember picture]
\node (B) {Node 2};
\stoptikzpicture
\starttikzpicture[overlay,remember picture]
\draw (B) --++(0,0.5) -| (A);
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

But nothing appears and is considered a fatal error when running. I wonder if there are some libraries or options in TikZ that are exclusive to LaTeX. If options such as `remember picture` cannot be used in Context, is there an alternative?

Comment: that's not a MWE, just a snippet of your code. a MWE is fully compilable.

Comment: @Muhammed Hashim: No problem on my PC with your code. The code is compilable when running `context`, no errors occur. A small improvement could be to write `\starttikzpicture[remember picture,baseline=(A.base)] \node (A) {Node 1};` for correct baseline of the node with the surrounding text.

Comment: @napahnael It is compilable. Simply run context on it.

Comment: If you are running lmtx, it could be that you have not copied the folder with modules. What I'm trying to say is that it could be good to know what version you run. It could also be useful to see what error you get.

Comment: Who downvoted this?  The question is legitimate, well researched, and very good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem in ConTeXt, which [defines](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/caee9d5ac3c65f78671a9786318358cd647247eb/tex/context/base/mkiv/back-pdf.mkiv#L96-L97)

```
\def\lastxpos{\clf_lastxpos}
\def\lastypos{\clf_lastypos}
```

and [further down](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/caee9d5ac3c65f78671a9786318358cd647247eb/tex/context/base/mkiv/back-pdf.mkiv#L206-L207)

```
\let\pdflastxpos\lastxpos
\let\pdflastypos\lastypos
```

where `\clf_lastxpos` and `\clf_lastypos` simply expand to numbers.  This means that `\pdflastxpos` and `\pdflastypos` can no longer be used as registers.  A simply workaround would be to wrap them in `\numexpr`.  I have reported this on the mailing list: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-context/2019/003602.html

```
\unprotect
% This fixes the present bug
\unexpanded\def\pdflastxpos{\numexpr\clf_lastxpos\relax}
\unexpanded\def\pdflastypos{\numexpr\clf_lastypos\relax}
% This might be needed if you run PGF 3.1.3
% see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/675
\def\XC@tgt@mod#1{#1}
\def\XC@sdef#1#2{\edef#1{#2}}
\protect
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
\starttikzpicture[remember picture]
     \node (A) {Node 1};
\stoptikzpicture
Hi world
\starttikzpicture[remember picture]
    \node (B) {Node 2};
\stoptikzpicture
\starttikzpicture[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw (B) --++(0,0.5) -| (A);
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```